# Uniformization theorem with boundary in the non-compact case

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a simply connected (and therefore orientable) smooth $2$-manifold with non-empty and connected boundary. Suppose that the interior $\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)$ is endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$ (which does **not** necessarily extend to all of $\Sigma$). Furthermore, let $u:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which is harmonic and strictly positive on $\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)$, and which vanishes identically on $\partial\Sigma$. Now let $H$ be the open upper half-plane $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\operatorname{Im}z>0\}$, and let $\overline{H}$ be the closed upper half-plane. Is there then a conformal equivalence $f:\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)\to H$, which extends to a homeomorphism $\Sigma\to\overline{H}$?

We can certainly find a conformal equivalence $f:\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)\to H$: apply the uniformization theorem (for Riemann surfaces without boundary) to $\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)$ to conclude that $\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)$ is conformally equivalent to either $\mathbb{C}$ or $H$. Letting $v:\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic conjugate for $u$, we see that $\exp(-u-iv)$ is a non-constant, bounded and holomorphic function on $\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)$. A conformal equivalence with $\mathbb{C}$ would therefore contradict Liouville's theorem, and we thus have a conformal equivalence $f:\operatorname{int}(\Sigma)\to H$.

However, as far as I can see, the above argument does not in any way say anything about the boundary behavior of $f$. Is there a version of uniformization which takes into account the boundary?

Comment: You have to explain what you exactly mean by "$2$-manifold with boundary". A 2-manifold (surface) has no boundary. There is the notion of "bordered surface". Its boundary is a 1-manifold. But this $1$ manifold may consist of circles and open intervals. For example, an open disk with half of the circle added is a bordered surface whose boundary is homeomorphic to an interval.